# Array unrolling in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to understand array unrolling in Posh and the following puzzles me. In this example I return the array wrapped in another array (using a comma), which basically gives me the original array after the outer array gets unrolled on return. Why then do I get a correct result (just the array) when I indirectly wrap the result by using the array operator (@) on a variable with the result, but get an array in an array if I use @ directly on the function? Does @ operator behave differently for different types of its parameter? 
Is there any PS help article for the @ operator and the array unrolling?

```
function Unroll
{
    return ,@(1,2,3)
}

Write-Host "No wrapper"
$noWrapper = Unroll #This is array[3]
$noWrapper | % { $_.GetType() }

Write-Host "`nWrapped separately"
$arrayWrapper = @($noWrapper) #No change, still array[3]
$arrayWrapper | % { $_.GetType() }

Write-Host "`nWrapped directly"
$directArrayWrapper = @(Unroll) #Why is this array[1][3] then?
$directArrayWrapper | % { $_.GetType() }
Write-Host "`nThe original array in elem 0"
$directArrayWrapper[0] | % { $_.GetType() }
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using the comma operator in your `Unroll` function?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the comma operator from the `Unroll` function, it behaves at you should expect.

```
function Unroll
{
    return @(1,2,3)
}
```

In this case `$arrayWrapper = @($noWrapper)` is the same as `$directArrayWrapper = @(Unroll)`.

You may find more information about array unrolling with [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701831/powershell-pass-system-object-without-unrolling) and in this [article about array literals In PowerShell](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2007/01/23/array-literals-in-powershell.aspx)

Comment: This is of course true, but you don't always have access to the original code, or cannot change it, as it's e.g. a library. The question was more about why this thing happens and how to have a consistent way of handling it regardless of how exactly the array is returned to you.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872146/powershell-how-exactly-does-the-rhs-of-the-f-operator-work), it seems that

> Putting the results (an array) within a grouping expression (or
>   subexpression e.g. $()) makes it eligible again for unrolling.

which seems to be what happen here.